# Help adding files to new Subversion repository

Tags: svn, import, repository

I have an application running on my server which currently is not using any version control.  I would like to start using Subversion version control and have signed up for a hosted Subversion Repository.

My question is, how do I populate my hosted Subversion repository?  Do I need to install Subversion on my server as well as having the hosted repository?  What is the easiest most straightforward way to populate the Subversion repository.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Russ

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following procedure:

```
#create trunk directory on hosted server
svn mkdir http://hosted-server-url/trunk -m"trunk created"

# checkout your trunk directory
svn co http://hosted-server-url/trunk
cd trunk
# copy your unversioned sources to the trunk directory
cp -R ../path/unversioned/sources/ .
# add and commit your sources
svn add
svn ci -m"initial import"
```

Another option is `svn import`.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere you want to access your subversion repository you need to install a subversion *client*, with which you checkout/checkin (or export) your files.